# Get Ancestor Class Name that Defines CONST in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, class-constants

I have a class hierarchy in PHP and in some of the parent classes I have defined a constant, let's assume that constant is called `TYPE` for my example.

I want to be able to pass in a valid value for `TYPE` that one of my classes may have defined and then get back the eldest most parent class that defined the constant *(what I'm calling 'origin class' for that constant.)* I have written the following code and it works, but it feels heavy and I was wondering if there was a better, more performant way to do this?

```
<?php

class Foo {
    const TYPE = 'idiom';
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class Baz extends Bar {}

function get_type_origin_class( $class, $type ) {
  $origin_class = false;
  $ref = new ReflectionClass( $class );
  while ( $ref && $type == $ref->getConstant( 'TYPE' ) ) {
    $origin_class = $ref->getName();
    $ref = $ref->getParentClass();
  }
  return $origin_class;
}

echo get_type_origin_class( 'Baz', 'idiom' ); // Echos: Foo
echo get_type_origin_class( 'Bar', 'idiom' ); // Echos: Foo
echo get_type_origin_class( 'Foo', 'idiom' ); // Echos: Foo
```

Comment: To get feedback on a working code, you may instead post this in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel Thanks; [**done**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33623).